# 'first argument must be string or compiled pattern' error in tf-idf vectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

dfff is a Dataframes that already been tokenized and will be used to convert to tf-idf by using tfidfvectorizer.

This is dfff sample:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

then I create a tfidfvectorizer one

```
tfidf_vecer2 = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', token_pattern=None)
```

then I ran this code:

```
tfidf_vectorr= tfidf_vecer2.fit_transform(dfff)
tfidf_array = np.array(tfidf_vectorr.todense())
```

suddenly, TypeError occurred as an output and I still can't figure it out.
I tried to use a list instead of a dataframe but it still error. this is an output:

> TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your example dataframe, but let's assume it's something like this:

```
import nltk

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':["Though worlds of wanwood leafmeal lie",
"And yet you will weep and know why"]})
df['tokenized'] = df['text'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)

                                    text                                     tokenized
0  Though worlds of wanwood leafmeal lie  [Though, worlds, of, wanwood, leafmeal, lie]
1     And yet you will weep and know why   [And, yet, you, will, weep, and, know, why]
```

Then you need a dummy function use as tokenizer, in order to leave the input as it is:

```
def func(x):
    return x

tfidf_vec = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=func,analyzer='word',
preprocessor=func,token_pattern=None)

tfidf_vec.fit(df['tokenized'])
```